# How to update, and then select the updated data with Python and DBUtils PersistentDB?

Tags: python-3.x

There are two Python scripts. Script A keeps reading the database for records and then send out messages. Script B keeps finding data and inserting into the database. Both of them keeps running without being terminated.

If there are unhandled records in the database, when script A starts, script A can see these records, and handle them correctly. Script A is now idle. After some time, script B insert some new records. However, script A cannot see these newly added records.

In script B, after inserting the records, I have connection.commit(). The records do in the database.

script A does not work correctly when:

```
persist = PersistentDB(pymysql, host=DB_HOST, port=DB_PORT, user=DB_USERNAME, passwd=DB_PASSWORD, db=DB_DATABASE, charset='utf8mb4')

while True:
    connection = persist.connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.exec("SELECT...")
```

script A works correctly when:

```
while True:
    persist = PersistentDB(pymysql, host=DB_HOST, port=DB_PORT, user=DB_USERNAME, passwd=DB_PASSWORD, db=DB_DATABASE, charset='utf8mb4')
    connection = persist.connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.exec("SELECT...")
```

Should I really use the PersistentDB in this way? It seems to override the persist connection pool everytime I declare it. Please tell me what is the correct way to do it.

P.S.
Connecting to MySQL 8 with Python 3, pymysql and DBUtils

Comment: You should update your question with the db you are using, and the python package you are using to connect to the db. +1